# Array List Overwriting inside loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist

thanks in advance for any help you can give me! Basically I have an arraylist, with three words per line separated by commas. I want to separate the strings on the comma to make a new array list with one string per line. I am stuck because within my loop is overwriting the arraylist each time around, so my new array list only contains the last line (3 strings split on the comma) of the orignal array list (array1). I have declared the second array list outside of the loop but it is still overwriting each time around. Its probably something really silly but here is the code, any help or pointers much appreciated!..

```
String[] array = new String[array1.size()];
List<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {
array = ((array1.get(i)).split(","));
array2 = Arrays.asList(array1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add  **array2.addAll** instead of **array2 =** in this way you are going to append the results of spit operation

```
   String[] array = new String[array1.size()];
   List<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {
    array = ((array1.get(i)).split(","));
     array2.addAll(Arrays.asList(array1));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `array1` contains lines of text it should be something like this:

```
List<String> array1 = ... // your read lines
List<String> splitted = new LinkedList<String();

for(String line : array1) {
    String[] splittedLine = line.split(",");
    splitted.addAll(Arrays.asList(splittedLine));
}
```

Basically, your problem was that you assigned *new list* to `array2` instead of adding elements to it.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear, but my guess is that instead of *overwriting* the list

```
array2 = Arrays.asList(array1);
```

you want to *append* to it

```
array2.addAll(Arrays.asList(array1));
```

But note that this gives you multiple elements per line, you may be better of with a List of Lists or List of Arrays (one entry per line, with each of those entries a list of fields).